# Android reliable periodic gps tracking

Tags: android, gps, android-wake-lock

**Many similar posts exist but none of them contains the doze mode problematic with alarmmanager and short periodic updates.**

Goal: Receive periodic interrupts to update location with the help of GPS

Requirements:

- Periodic updates of the location mainly with the help of gps, relative exact 1 per minute (+- 10sec)
- works on newer android devices (which includes doze)

Actual Idea:

- using a alarm manager inside a service which is "Start_Sticky". Thie alarmmanager sends every minute a broadcast to notify the gps-receiver to read the location and send it to the server. The Alarmmanager is configured with AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP.

Problem:

- **The alarmmanager is not reliable anymore since the functionality of doze**. When the device is in doze the alarmmanager is not sent.
- I do not receive location updates from the gps while the screen is off

Additional Information regarding this problem:

- There are multiple information about this like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903877/android-send-location-data-in-background-periodically-every-30-seconds-and-as) , but it seems that with doze the alarmmanager is not anymore reliable - means this solution is not usable anymore.

*Note: Neither setAndAllowWhileIdle() nor setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() can fire alarms more than once per 9 minutes, per app.* [src](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#assessing_your_app)

**Question:**

Which components do I need to achieve this ? Foreground Service, Alarmmanager, Wakelock ?

Comment: "Periodic updates, relativ exact 1 per minute (+- 10sec)" -- have the user add your app to the battery optimization whitelist, or build your own custom ROM. "user cannot kill service" -- build your own custom ROM. "using a alarm manager inside a service which is "Start_Sticky"." -- the user can still "kill service" in multiple ways via the Settings app. "Wakelock" -- GPS fixes take time. AFAIK, you will need to keep the device CPU powered on continuously (or nearly so). This may make your app unpopular with users.

Comment: I simplified the problem. A custom ROM is no option. My problem is mainly the periodic updates.. I do not understand why this could be so hard ?

Comment: "I do not understand why this could be so hard ?" -- because it is bad for the user's battery life. Too many developers do too many things in the background that users do not like, and so Google is "tightening the screws" to prevent developers from abusing the battery this way, unless the user opts into that behavior (adds the app to the battery optimization whitelist in Settings).

Comment: That's reasonable! But since setExactAndAllowWhileIdle only runs once per 9 minutes - there is absolutely no way to execute something once a minute on Android 6 without having the screen on -right ? Even if the app is in optimization whitelist (which is acceptable for us since the user accepts this in using the app - it is more or less the core feature why he uses the app)

Comment: "Even if the app is in optimization whitelist" -- AFAIK, that should be enough. But, beyond that, `AlarmManager` is largely unnecessary in your scenario, as you will already have a process running. Use Java's `ScheduledExecutorService` to get control periodically in a regular `Service`. Or, rely on `requestLocationUpdates()` (or the equivalent for Play Services' location API) to deliver updates as needed to your running process.

Comment: Okay thank you - I have to read about this optimization whitelist.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#support_for_other_use_cases -- actually, according to that bit of documentation, the whitelist does not affect `AlarmManager`, but, again, you should not need that.

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding from my side. Since it is not defined after which period of time doze begins to work, I just need that my app is still working as the device moves into sleep. AFAIK doze begins after "long" time of no interrupts which is not the case in my situation. It is more like a fitness application which tracks the user after screen is off

Comment: @ChristofBuechi now that 1.75 years have passed, can you answer your own question, even if it isn't the optimal answer?  I have the same question, but without the 9 minute problem (my need is only every 30 minutes or so).

Answer (score 0):

Use push notification and set it to high priority, that is probably the most reliable way to keep the app running for gps tracking while it is in deep sleep mode. I setup a 30 mins interval and keep sending notifications, the phone doesn't wake up and screen turned on but I do noticed the GPS still sort of works.