# Continue running time in background unity and pop notification

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, background-process

I am developing a game in unity, I included the time in it after 5 minutes player will get 1 life and i want my code to pop up notification when the player gets the maximum lifes that is 10 when even the game is closed so i need to run the time in the background here is the code that i have created.

```
void OnApplicationQuit(){   
    while(lifes < 10){      
        if (lifes < 10) {
            seconds -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (seconds <= 0) {
               minutes -= 1;
               seconds  = 60; } 
            if (minutes < 0) {
               minutes = 4;
               lifes   += 1;
               PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Lifes", lifes);
            }     
        }else{
             LocalNotification.SendNotification(1, 5, "Tilty Bob", "Your lifes are full play to unlock next", new Color32(0xff, 0x44, 0x44, 255));
             }
    }
}
```

Any help will be very appreciated i try to figure out this from last 15 days all over the internet but did not get the answer.

Comment: I would just calculate the time when user's life is at maximum, then set an [alarm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001245/set-an-alarm-from-my-application), no battery draining needed. And of course run a logic on startup to update the player's life if it's started before the life is full. Utilizing GCM could also work, but your app would need online connection & server.

Answer (score 2):

From what I have understand, you want your app to run in background.

But OnApplicationQuit() is called only 1 time : when you quit your app. So there is no background working (check the API : "called when the user stops playMode").

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html

What you are looking for is a **service**:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/538264/android-services-running-unity.html

good luck